# How to merge channel images into RGB image

Tags: python, image, go

I read image data arrays respectively from three datasets(blue,green,red channel) in a HDF5 file,which is a format of file for storing data.the data type are uint16,the arrays are 2D with length of 2748*2748.The py code is as below(maybe some tricky but I don't know the reason behind it):

```
from pyhdf.SD import SD, SDC
from PIL import Image
import h5py

hdf5File = h5py.File('channelImgData.HDF', 'r')
...
# Channel01,02,03 are all arrays reading from a .HDF file,i.e,[65535,65535,...,65535] for length of 2748*2748
# the confusions here are multiply the data by 0.1 and convert the generated image into gray...
r = Image.fromarray(Channel03*0.1).convert('L')
g = Image.fromarray(Channel02*0.1).convert('L')
b = Image.fromarray(Channel01*0.1).convert('L')

# merge the gray images into a RGB image...
image_output = Image.merge("RGB", (r, g, b))
image_output.save("map_picture.bmp)
```

And the result is as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFq0Q.png)

I tried the following with Go in my own way :

```
    rect := image.Rect(0, 0, 2748, 2748)
    imgSet := image.NewRGBA64(rect)

    for i := 0; i < length; i++ {
        x := i % 2748
        y := i / 2748
        pixel := color.RGBA64{
            // channel1,2,3 are the same with the above py code
            R: channel3[i], 
            G: channel2[i],
            B: channel1[i],
            A: 0,
        }
        imgSet.Set(x, y, color.RGBA64Model.Convert(pixel))
    }

    outFile, err := os.Create("hybrid.bmp")
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
        return
    }
    defer outFile.Close()
    err = bmp.Encode(outFile, imgSet)
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
        return
    }
}
```

The result image is recognizable but very lossy...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9YVV.jpg)

I find the problem lies in I wrongly implemented the the py function image.fromarray.
So how to implement the same behaviour as image.fromarray using go?

Comment: In your Python example, is that the Image class from the PIL module?

Comment: yes,and this is the py code that generate the expeted image written by others:                   
`// data are arrays reading from .hdf file,i.e [65535,65535...,65535]                             
r = Image.fromarray(dataInRedChan*0.1).convert('L')                            
g = Image.fromarray(dataInGreenChan*0.1).convert('L')                           
b = Image.fromarray(dataInBlueChan*0.1).convert('L')                      
image_output = Image.merge("RGB", (r, g, b))
image_output.save("expetedImg.bmp")                                      
`
How can I copy these steps in Go code?

Comment: `color.RGBA64` contains the components as 16-bit `uint16` values. Are you sure the `red`, `green` and `blue` slices also contain 16-bit values and not 8-bit values? Please post what the `red`, `green` and `blue` slices are.

Comment: red,green,blue are all 2D data arrays(2748*2748),i.e,[65535,65535...65535] for the length of 2748*2748,it's obviously uint16 in Go

Comment: What do you want more exactly to obtain with the newly constructed image? Do you want to copy the pixel values from an image to another one? Please give a better description.

Comment: we cannot reproduce the problem just with the code. we need to see the input and how do you convert the input into those slices.

Comment: I repost the question, please recheck the illustration above:)